# View controller not being released by navigation controller for a long time?

Tags: iphone

I'm doing some debugging and leak checking, so I've got some NSLog output in a few of my app's view controllers and such.  Then I noticed one particular controller appears to be releasing quite a while after the others, even though the navigation controller is popping it off the view stack. Every other view is immediately unloaded and released.  Perplexed.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but often the navigation controller is referenced somewhere else. If it is, set those references to nil to allow the autorelease to happen.

Comment: The navigation controller or the view controller?

Comment: There's no GC on iOS (currently).  So setting pointers to nil by itself doesn't affect object retention or collection.